# MVC3 JSON Telerik MVC TreeView Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I am trying to bind data from json.  In the controller, I am sending

```
......
public JsonResult LoadTree()
........
return Json(jn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In debug I get the values in jn (47 items, each has two enteries (text and value).

In the view, I am using the following script:

```
function onDataBinding(e) {
    var url = 'CourseCases/LoadTree';
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var treeview = $("#TreeView").data("tTreeView");
            treeview.bindTo(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It does not work, alert shows object, object; and the treeview is blank!
Any idea why?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the properties that you are sending should be called `Value` and `Text` instead of `value` and `text`. Here's an example that works fine for me.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoadTree()
    {
        var jn = new[] 
        {
            new { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
            new { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
            new { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
        };
        return Json(jn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBinding(e) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("LoadTree")';
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { },
            success: function (data) {
                var treeview = $("#TreeView").data("tTreeView");
                treeview.bindTo(data);
            }
        });
    }    
</script>

@(Html
    .Telerik()
    .TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .ClientEvents(events =>
    {
        events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding");
    })
)
```

Comment: Thank you Darin for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should call treeview.bindTo in the callback method of $.post directly. I guess with the current code you might bind the treeview to jsonObject == jn before jn == content is ensured in the callback. If you alert you add a big delay and it gives the AJAX post enough time to complete and run the callback.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I see the json data when I debug the program in the controller, but when I have alert in the view it is null!!